# AVAudioSequencer.tempoTrack not sending SetTempo messages

Tags: ios, avfoundation, midi, coremidi

I'm trying to get tempo related messages from the `AVAudioSequencer.tempoTrack`.

```swift
class TempoHandler {
    private var midiEndpoint = MIDIEndpointRef()
    private var midiClient = MIDIClientRef()
    private let sequencer: AVAudioSequencer

    public init(sequencer: AVAudioSequencer) {
        self.sequencer = sequencer
    }

    func setup() {
        var status = MIDIClientCreateWithBlock("TempoHandler.Client" as CFString, &midiClient, nil)
        try checkStatus(status: status, error: SequencerMIDIContextError.createMidiClient)

        status = MIDIDestinationCreateWithBlock(midiClient, "TempoHandler.In" as CFString, &midiEndpoint, midiIO)
        try checkStatus(status: status, error: SequencerMIDIContextError.createMidiDestination)

        sequencer.tempoTrack.destinationMIDIEndpoint = midiEndpoint
    }

    private func midiIO(_ packetList: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>, _ src: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        let packets = packetList.pointee
        var packet = packets.packet
        for _ in 0 ..< packets.numPackets {
            print("TempoHandler received " + String(format:"%02X", packet.data.0))
            packet = MIDIPacketNext(&packet).pointee
        }
    }
}
```

- My `sequencer` is fully loaded with a MIDI file before I call `setup()` then `sequencer.prepareToPlay()` if that matters.
- The MIDI file contains multiple SetTempo meta messages that are audibly well handled by the sequencer.
- When instead setting my `midiEndpoint` as a destination to another track (`sequencer.tracks[0]`), my handler does output note messages.

But with the tempo track, no MIDI message is received. Is there something I'm missing ?

[EDIT] I tried both variations:

- load my MIDI file in the sequencer with the `AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions.smf_ChannelsToTracks` option and listen to both the `tempoTrack` and the last track of the `tracks` array. I would expect to receive meta messages on either this last track or `tempoTrack`, because the doc states:

> /** @typedef AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions
> @abstract Determines whether data on different MIDI channels is mapped to multiple tracks, or
> if the tracks are preserved as-is.
> @discussion
> If AVMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks is set, the loaded MIDI Sequence will contain a
> tempo track, one track for each MIDI channel that is found in the SMF, and one track for
> SysEx and/or MetaEvents (this will be the last track in the sequence).

> If AVMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks is not set, the loadad MIDI Sequence will
> contain one track for each track that is found in the SMF, plus a tempo track (if not found
> in the SMF).
>
> API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.11), ios(9.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0))
> */

- use `MIDIDestinationCreateWithProtocol` as `MIDIDestinationCreateWithBlock` is deprecated for iOS 14+

Unfortunately with no success.